# Updating database on bootstrap button click

Tags: php, mysql, buttonclick

I am trying to send a value to my mysql database, I am very new to php/bootstrap programming and I've tried everything but most of the guides are beyond my understanding. Please guide me in the right path so on the button click the button will update the specific database.

Here's what the button click will do:
on Uninstall button click it will send update the database like

UPDATE activate="No" FROM software WHERE uid(or id)="same id of the row where the button is clicked" [I know this mysql query is wrong]

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="css/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="css/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-12 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S/N</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>IP Address</th>
        <th>UID</th>
        <th>Activation</th>
        <th>Command</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody>

    <?php
    $count_rows = 0;
    include 'database_connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT `date`, `ip`, `id`, `activate` FROM `software`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
        $count_rows++;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count_rows ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ip']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['activate']; ?> <td><button type="button" id="btn-uninstall" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Uninstall</button> <button type="button" id="btn-install" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Install</button> <button type="button" id="btn-upgrade" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Upgrade</button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="js/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's screenshot of the page: https://image.ibb.co/eToeaz/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to happen instantly then use AJAX to send request to the php server, see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp for more info.

if you want it with redirecting then use

```
$conn = new mysqli("DBservername", "DBusername", "DBpassword", "DBname");
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    $errormsg = ("Database Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
    return $errormsg;
}
$res=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'something'");
$row=$res->fetch_array();
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res); // if fetch correct it returns must be 1 row
mysqli_close($conn);
if( $count == 1 ) etc
```

send query, update, delete etc.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE 'something';
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Rough and bad php code but should work.

Edit after i understand what you actually asked:
When rendering results from database, anchor each button to redirect to a page /update/{rowid} or /update.php?id={rowid}

and in that link execute the query with conditions and etc.

Comment: I am confused, I want to update the database on button click, why am I again retrieving data?

Comment: $conn = new mysqli("DBservername", "DBusername", "DBpassword", "DBname");
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `something` = 'to something' WHERE `its id is some id`;
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
try this code instead

Answer (score 0):

You can send request to server by this code.

```
    $con = new mysqli_connect("servername", "username", "password", "name");
    if(!$con)
    {
       die("DB CONNECTION ERROR");

    }
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'something'");
    $row=$result->fetch_array();
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    mysqli_close($con);
    if( $count == 1 )
```

Comment: I am confused, I want to update the database on button click, why am I again retrieving data?

Comment: You check your code again and see are you updating correctly or not

Comment: my code is generating the table from db just fine, i want to change database value on the button click